# How to lemmatize a corpus with a particular dictionary in R?”

Tags: r, text-mining, lemmatization

I'm trying to perform `lemmatization` on a corpus, using the function `lemmatize_strings()` as an argument to `tm_map()` of `tm` package.

But I want to use my own dictionary ("lexico" - first column with the full word form in lower case, while the second column has the corresponding replacement lemma).

I tried to use:

```
corpus<-tm_map(corpus, lemmatize_strings)
```

But didn't work...
When I use:

```
lemmatize_strings(corpus[[1]], dictionary = lexico)
```

I have no problem!

How can I put the my dictionary "lexico" in the fuction tm_map()?

Sorry for this question, it'is my first attempt to make some text mining, at the age of 48.

To be more understandable, my corpus are composed by 2000 documents; an extract from the first document:

```
corpus[[1]][[1]]

[9] "..."

[10] "Nos últimos dias da passada legislatura, a maioria de direita aprovou duas leis que significam enormes recuos nos direitos das cidadãs do país. Fizeram tábua rasa do pronunciamento das cidadãs e cidadãos do país em referendo, optando por humilhar e tentar culpabilizar as mulheres que abortam por sua livre escolha. Estas duas leis são a Lei n.º 134/2015 e a Lei n.º 136/2015, de setembro. A primeira prevê o pagamento de taxas moderadoras na interrupção de gravidez quando for realizada, por opção da mulher, nas primeiras 10 semanas de gravidez. A segunda representa a primeira alteração à Lei n.º 16/2007, de 17 de abril, sobre exclusão de ilicitude nos casos de interrupção voluntária da gravidez."
```

Then worked on a dictionary file (lexico) with this configuration:

```
lexico[1:10,]
           termo         lema pos.tag
1             aa            a NCMP000
2           aais          aal NCMP000
3            aal          aal NCMS000
4      aaleniano    aaleniano NCMS000
5     aalenianos    aaleniano NCMP000
6     ab-rogação   ab-rogação NCFS000
7    ab-rogações   ab-rogação NCFP000
8   ab-rogamento ab-rogamento NCMS000
9  ab-rogamentos ab-rogamento NCMP000
10   ab-rogáveis   ab-rogável  AQ0CP0
```

When I use the function `lemmatize_strings(corpus[[1]], dictionary = lexico)`, it works correctly and give de document of corpus nº1 lemmatized with lemmas from my dictionary.

The problem that I have, is with this function:

```
> corpus<-tm_map(corpus, lemmatize_strings, dictionary = lexico)
Warning messages:
1: In stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(x, numreg) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
2: In stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(x, numreg) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
> corpus[[1]][[1]]
[1] ""
```

This simply destroy all my documents in the corpus

```
> corpus
<<VCorpus>>
Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
Content:  documents: 2000
```

Thnks in advance for your reply!

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? To make it easier to get help, can you provide a minimal reproducible example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. For your question in particular, it would be helpful to have a small example `corpus`, your `lemmatize_strings` function and a small portion of `lexico`. Finally, note that  `lemmatize_strings` takes an additional argument, `dictionary`, which you are not passing to `tm_map`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments / help. I allready put more information in my original question.

Comment: One more question. Are you looking for a solution that uses the `tm` package specifically? Or are you happy with the solution which uses `quanteda` instead?

Comment: The error you are getting is because `tm` doesn't accept a data frame here. What you are trying to do is, to my knowledge, not possible in `tm`. The two options I see are to use `quanteda`, which has a function for this purpose. Or to write your own function building on `stringi` (which is what `tm` is doing under the hood).

Comment: I used this function that works, I think - for (i in 1:length(corpus)) {corpus [[i]][[1]]<-lemmatize_strings(corpus [[i]][[1]], dictionary = lexico)}

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, use the `quanteda` package for this:

```
library("quanteda")
text <- "This is a test sentence. We can lemmatize it using quanteda."
dict <- data.frame(
  word = c("is", "using"),
  lemma = c("be", "use"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

toks <- tokens(text, remove_punct = TRUE)
toks_lemma <- tokens_replace(toks,
                             pattern = dict$word,
                             replacement = dict$lemma,
                             case_insensitive = TRUE, 
                             valuetype = "fixed")
toks_lemma
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
 [1] "This"      "be"        "a"         "test"      "sentence"  "We"        "can"       "lemmatize"
 [9] "it"        "use"       "quanteda"
```

The function is very fast and despite the name was mainly ceated for lemmatization.